# discord.py How to get a custom emoji's url (NOT as a command)

Tags: python, url, discord, discord.py, emoji

I found an answer online which looks like this:

```py
@bot.command()
async def geturl(emoji: discord.Emoji):
    await bot.say(emoji.url)
```

But my bot needs to know the url of an emoji right after it's put in a database, so this won't do. I tried doing something like:

```py
emoji = discord.PartialEmoji(name="<:duckysleep:1059974724588945479>")

print(emoji.url)
```

But this just... won't work for some reason. The console is blank.

How can I get an emoji's url from its name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work:

```py
emoji = discord.PartialEmoji(name="<:duckysleep:1059974724588945479>")
```

is because `"<:duckysleep:1059974724588945479>"` is **not the `name` of your emoji**, that is the entire format string to represent it in Discord, made up of `<animated?:name:id>`. The name is `duckysleep`.

To construct a `PartialEmoji`, pass the `name`, `id` & `animated` arguments separately. **Note**: the `name` is *not used* when building the URL, so if you only have the `id` then that's fine as well.

Alternatively, if you already have the entire string, you can use [`PartialEmoji.from_str()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=partialemoji#discord.PartialEmoji.from_str) to create one from the format string, as the name implies. That way you don't have to parse it yourself, and optionally make mistakes against it.

```py
emoji = PartialEmoji.from_str("<:duckysleep:1059974724588945479>")
```

Then you can just access the `.url` property to get the URL.

Comment: Wow thanks for such a detailed explanation, it all makes more sense to me now. And thanks for the `from_str()` function as well!

Comment: @Imaginary If it solved your issue you should mark my answer as correct

Comment: Done, btw is there a similar function for default emojis too?

Comment: If with "default emojis" you mean Unicode characters, those don't have a URL so that would be impossible. If you just want to create a PartialEmoji then you can pass the unicode char as the `name` attribute and leave the id at None.